# Specify path to Gemfile

Tags: ruby, bundler

How do I tell bundler to no search the `Gemfile` in the current directory but somewhere else?

I want to do

```
bundle install --some-option path/to/Gemfile
```

instead of

```
cd path/to & bundle install
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `--gemfile` option:

> --gemfile= The location of the Gemfile(5) which Bundler should use. This defaults to a Gemfile(5) in the current working
>   directory. In general, Bundler will assume that the location of the
>   Gemfile(5) is also the project's root and will try to find
>   Gemfile.lock and vendor/cache relative to this location.

Source: [Bundler manual](https://bundler.io/man/bundle-install.1.html)